# getelementbyid on dynamically created elements not working

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementbyid, setattribute

I am creating an element with this code. Setting the ID as it should be set. (Do I need the validateonparse?):

```
$sectionContainer = $dom->createElement('div', $section);
$sectionContainer->setAttribute("id", $section);
$sectionContainer->setIdAttribute("id", TRUE);
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$divup->parentNode->insertBefore($sectionContainer, $divup);


echo 'avant'."</br>";
echo $section;
print_r($dom->getElementById($section)->getAttribute('id'));
echo 'apres'."</br>";
```

But I get this:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

So it can't locate the element I just created, why?

Answer (score 0):

Hey_ there,

the problem is not with `$dom->validateOnParse = true;`.

Your error comes from this line of code - `$sectionContainer->setIdAttribute("id", TRUE);`.

If you want to set id attribute of [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) like `<div id="myId"></div>` you only need `$domElement->setAttribute("id", "myId");` which you already have.

[DOMElement::setIdAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setidattribute.php) is actually indicating that this attribute is unique identifier which has nothing to do with the `id="myId"` attribute

> (PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> DOMElement::setIdAttribute — Declares the attribute
>   specified by name to be of type ID
>
> **Description**
>
> public void DOMElement::setIdAttribute ( string $name , bool $isId )
>
> Declares the attribute name to be of type ID.

Well it is not very clear what is **type ID**, but I can say that it is something different from `id` attribute of html element.

Check demo [**HERE**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe7863510728d2f570726f93f2e339d67c051bea)

Comment: In your example, what does Before and After output stays for? There is only single output between Before and After. So it's confusing.

Comment: I don't know also. I see that the code on this platform can be overwritten and I guess someone edit it... The important in this topic is that if you want to set the `id` attribute you do it with [**setAttribute**](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) instead [**setIdAttribute**](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setidattribute.php)

Comment: I think that code with Before and After only confuses things.